# Assign value from VARIANT to BSTR * in plain C

Tags: c, com

I am using the following code to get the current URL in the browser.

```
...
BSTR url = NULL;
getUrl(&url);
...

void getUrl(BSTR *url){
...
VARIANT urlValue;
  VariantInit(&urlValue);
...
hr = IUIAutomationElement_GetCurrentPropertyVlue(pUrlBar,UIA_ValueValuePropertyId,&urlValue);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
  url= &urlValue.bstrVal;
  }
}
```

I am getting null from the variable `url`. I am wondering if I assigned correctly the value from the VARIANT `urlValue`. How do I get the value correctly?.

Comment: The calling code seems correct, but never assume a VARIANT's type, always check the vt field. That being said, it's possible it's in fact null, you're asking for UIA_ValueValuePropertyId on some automation element. You can use the Inspect tool from SDK w/o any code to check if this is also null.

Comment: Hi @SimonMourier tks for your help. How would I check the vt field?

Comment: Check urlValue.vt. It should be equal to VT_BSTR

Comment: Generally speaking, shouldn't you have `*url = urlValue.bstrVal;` I guess C is not giving a good warning. For sure make `urlValue.vt == VT_BSTR;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into your function getUrl() you are passing a BSTR*.

```
void getUrl(BSTR*);
```

You have to dereference the pointer to properly set the value of the original BSTR:

```
if (SUCCEED(hr) && urlValue.vt == VT_BSTR) {
   *url = urlValue.bstrVal;
}
```

Consider where you might have an int pointer:

```
// bad implementation
void getInt(int* pint) {
   pint = 3; // bad, but basically what you had originally
}

//good
void getInt(int* pint) {
   *pint = 3; // correct, dereferencing allows changing the int that pint points to
}
```

Some people call that the "call by reference" method for passing arguments in C. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm or https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-call-by-value-and-call-by-reference/

Don't get it confused with C++ which has real call by reference with a different syntax, but under the hood the compiler will treat roughly the same.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Tks @Joseph Willconxson for your excellent answer. Have a good day.

Comment: The original code plus this modification will work, but it feels a bit sloppy. The API you call fills in the local variant, then you yank the BSTR from it and act like the variant doesn’t exist. That will work, but it’s cleaner to reset (VariantInit again) urlValue to make it explicit that you transferred out ownership of the BSTR. This will avoid nasty surprises if someone has to change the code later (or move to C++ and introduce a Variant helper class). At least heavily comment! Or maybe this *is* “the C way” and I’m just too entrenched on C++ thinking?

Comment: Depending on who/what the source of the variant is, I usually call VariantChangeType to ensure I *do * have a BSTR. But I don’t think that is necessary for this particular API call.

Comment: IDK really what is the C way. I started out with C++ and if I was coding in C++ I'd use a variant_t or CComVariant and be explicit about transferring ownership of the BSTR. The original code would have at least given a good warning or even failed to compile to C++ when trying to set a BSTR* to a BSTR without dereferencing.